# Is It possible to call methods from a subclass from a base class type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, pointers, abstract-class

Hello everyone and thanks for reading,
I'm new to working with classes and I've ran into an issues with making array's of objects,
I have a base class, and an array of the same type, I'd like to know if it's a possibility to
make subclasses of the base class type and put them into an array and call methods that're not
in the base class, sorry if this is a bad question and my apologies if my wording is off,

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    BaseClass* ObjectList[10];
    ObjectList[0] = new SubClass;
    ObjectList[0]->Load(10);
    ObjectList[0]->OtherFunction();     // How Can I Do This?
    return 0;
}


class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void Load(int Num) = 0;
};


class SubClass : public BaseClass
{
    void Load(int Num) override
    {
        std::cout << Num << std::flush;
    }
    void OtherFunction()
    {
        // Do Something
    }
};
```

Thanks

Edit -
My intent is to have a simple base class with dozens and dozens of subclasses with different methods, and have an array of the base class,

Comment: 1.) You can make `OtherFunction` a virtual function in the `BaseClass` interface. 2.) If it doesn't make sense to do so, you can reconsider the wisdom of putting a mix of `BaseClass` and `SubClass` in the same container if you can't actually treat them the same. 3.) If you still have a compelling reason, you can `dynamic_cast` the base class pointer.

Comment: Thing is; my intent is to have upwards of dozens of a base class, I know in this example it is very simplified, Ill try and see if I can do anything with dyanamic_cast

Comment: Do you mean dozens of different instances of a base class and that's why you want them in an array, or dozens of different derived classes with different interfaces and you want instances of all of them to be in the _same_ array? If the latter I would really suggest trying to figure out what actually belongs together and maybe not putting absolutely everything in a single "one of everything" container.

Comment: What I've been working on is a game engine, and I have a base class "Level", and then sub classes for each level. the level manager needs to have an array of all the different sub classes of levels and call all the different methods from each sub class, in short, dozens of derived

Comment: another instance of this issue is each level has an array of objects,
and every object class derives from a base object class with universal and necessary
methods for every object, and each object has it's own methods that need to be called,

Comment: **Don't do it**. If the subsclasses represent levels in a game, you don't want the caller to know the praticularity of each level. You have to make a generic interface. In a good design, you always want to **avoid strong bidirectionnal dependencies**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always have more than one pointer (or reference) to the same object.

```
int main()
{
    BaseClass* ObjectList[10];
    SubClass TheSubclass;
    ObjectList[0] = &TheSubclass;
    ObjectList[0]->Load(10); // presumably in a loop
    TheSubclass.OtherFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works for me very well in fact, this is my second game engine, (first one failed), just finished setting up a wrapper from Direct2D and now I'm figuring out how to do the levels, objects, entities, events, etc, and I think this method of doing things is really neat, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to downcast your pointer to the real class (or at least a class having the method). You can use either a `static_cast` if you do not need any control, or a `dynamic_cast` if you want a run-time validation of the cast:

```
...
SubClass *psc = dynamic_cast<SubClass *>(ObjectList[0]);
if (psc != nullptr) {   // an invalid cast would set it to NULL
    psc->OtherFunction();
}
else {
    // process the error
}
```